# What are typical reasons the title/section font being different from the body font?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, titles

I'm using a conference's suggested document style file.  In my `main.tex`, I've added

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
```

which typesets the body correctly.  However, the title & all the section headings still use the "default" font.

What are some typical reasons for this, and how can I try to fix it?

(I do not have `titlesec` or `sectsty` included -- not in my main or in the conference cls file.)

Comment: This could be because the title font has been explicitly defined by the class itself to use one particular font. You will need to redefine the font used for titles.

Comment: What is your document class? Please add an MWE! With `article` the fonts seem to be the same ([output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcufT.png)).

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh you're right.  I found some code in the doc class that specifies those upfront.  So maybe I shouldn't change them after all...

Comment: I would suggest you not mess with the fonts at all for a conference paper  (substance over style).  That being said, try redefining `\normalfont`.

Comment: the whole point of using conference or journal class is that the editors of the proceedings get to choose fonts and design and authors lose that freedom. It's almost always a bad idea, and sometimes a block on submission, to use such a class then change the design.

Comment: Note that, although the previous comments are correct in general, depending on the field and/or the conference the templates are sometimes considered more of a suggestion and it is allowed to modify fonts and other design choices. However, this is not very common, and to be on the safe side it is better just to follow the template as provided.